# I am getting the error message "Please disable antivirus or close internet explorer" while installing android sdk. What should I do?

Tags: android, windows, sdk, windows-8.1

> I am getting the error message "Please disable antivirus or close internet explorer" while installing
>   android sdk. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

download the bundle [Eclipse including sdk](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i#download)